# Transparent view overlay for drawing

Tags: android, android-layout, overlay

I have app consisting of RelativeLayout, TableLayout and some buttons. Now I would like to draw a circle under point where user pressed on screen. One way to go is to extend View and add all the functionality inside, but I am wondering if there is any more elegant (general) solution?

I was thinking in way of transparent overlay, which you add to layout and it captures MotionEvent, draw circle on point of touch and passes event to underlying View component (so buttons are still clickable).

That way solution would be more reusable, as you can easily plug it in any project, but unfortunately I have no idea if it is doable that way. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can achieve what you want using `GestureOverlayView`.

Resources and examples are available:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureOverlayView.html
- http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html
- http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html#example

Comment: I took a look GestureOverlayView and then created my own class extending just View. It is importand to override dispatchDraw, first draw children and then your overlay, otherwise you are getting overdrwan by children in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if my suggestion is the best solution,but I would do the following:
Create a new class that extends Drawable.
Override the onDraw method and in there draw your circles on the canvas. 
Add a. addCircle(int x, int y); method to the drawable class which you will call each time you want to add a circle.

Then in you activity create a new objectof the above mentioned class and set it with context.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(your object) as your WindowBackground. Then where you handle your motionevent call this objects .addCircle method and your circle will be added.

Like this in your activity will be only several lines of code and it will be reusable.